# Navigate between outlet modals in Angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, angular2-routing, angular5

I can't handle navigation from one modal window to another.
I have routing module:

```
{
      path: 'modal1',
      component: Modal1Component,
      outlet: 'modal',
    }, {
      path: 'modal2',
      component: Modal2Component,
      outlet: 'modal',
    }
```

Main component: `MainComponent` and in its template i have

`<router-outlet name="modal"></router-outlet>`

So i am clicking a button that triggers

`this.router.navigate([this.router.url, { outlets: {modal: 'modal1'} }]);`

And in `Modal1Component` that is rendered i have a button for `modal2`. So i want to call `modal2` from `modal1`. How can i tell `router` to go to the parent route and then call:

`this.router.navigate([/* what should be here? */, { outlets: {modal: 'modal2'} }]);`

Comment: In the routes you show us, both path and outlet are exactly the same, did you copy it wrong ?

Comment: Sorry, it was typo. I updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're just changing the outlet in your router.navigate, but the route itself is not actually changing. And I don't think you actually require a named outlet to do what you're trying to achieve.

When you use router.navigate, you can specify if you want to navigate relatively from somewhere using the ActivatedRoute class. To do so, you have two options :

- navigate relatively from you current component and indicate in the path that you want to "go up" one level. Example :

  `this.router.navigate(['../modal2'], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute });`
- navigate directly from you parent. I would personaly use this one but both works. Example :

  `this.router.navigate(['modal2'], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute.parent });`

I created a mini repo with an example of what (I think) you're trying to achieve on : [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wuvucg).

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help. It just go back to parent url without `(modal:modal1)` in url

Comment: Hum this.router.url indicates the current url, I though your modals were some child components. Try "this.router.navigate('/modal1)" ?

Comment: `this.router.navigate(['/modal1']) ` navigates just to the root path `/modal1`. But i have parent route before it:
`/grandparentRoute/parentRoute/modal1`

Comment: Ok, can you show us what's in this.router.url when you use it to navigate to your modal ?

Comment: And the complete routes config please :)

Comment: Thanks for the repo, but the problem is that i want use something like `this.router.parentUrl` instead of hardcoded string `modal-parent` in `this.router.navigate`

Comment: Url when the `moda1` is active is:
`container/component1/component2/(modal:modal1)`. When i pressed 'open modal2' button i executes function where `this.router.url` is `container/component1/component2/(modal:modal1)`. The same as current url

Comment: Updated my answer and the repo :)

Comment: Thank you. Second variant for me works:
`this.router.navigate([{ outlets: {modal: 'modal2'} }], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute.parent });`

Answer (score 0):

Some service can be useful in this case, like in doc:

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: I think it is not good idea to create service for this, because it is only router responsibility